# importing and exporting modules in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, reactjs, require

I'm working in a React.js project which I need to import some JavaScript in others, and some others I have to export it.

For example I have `A.js` which needs some library:

```
var EventEmitter = require('EventEmitter');
var React = require('react');
//some code here
//some function definition
var fun = function(){...}
module.exports = fun;
```

And then I have another `B.js` which needs not only libraries but also my own JavaScript. For example `B.js` (I suppose both in the same folder):

```
var fun = require('./B.js');
var React = require('react');
//some other code here
```

I tried using the library [requirejs](http://www.requirejs.org) and also try something with npm and nodejs but I'm not sure how it works.
I'm using the [flux-chat example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-chat)

Comment: Your question is how you build your JavaScript for serving?

Answer (score 0):

First, if the code you specified for `A.js` and `B.js` aren't working for you, it would be because you're trying to require `B.js` inside of itself... I think what you're trying to do is require `A.js` into `B.js` like so:

**`B.js` fix:**

```
var fun = require('./A.js');
var React = require('react');
//some other code here
```

*notice that `fun` is requiring `A.js` now*

If the typo I noticed above isn't fixing your problem, continue reading on...

---

What exactly are you trying to do when you require `A.js` into `B.js`?

Without me knowing more of what you're trying to accomplish (or until I see the actual code inside of your `A.js` and `B.js` files), my best answer would be this:

**`A.js` would look something like:**

```
module.exports = function(){
    fun: function(param){...logic here...}
}
```

**`B.js` would look something like this:**

```
var React = require('react');
var A = require('./B.js');

var Whatever = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {A.fun('param value')}
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

If on the other hand, you're trying to export your `A.js` as a React component that you can require and add to another (`B.js`) React component... my answer would be different.

Answer (score -1):

RequireJS and npm are two different ways to resolve modules. People often use `bower` to download AMD/UMD supported libs, and add the path to the config file of RequireJS. RequireJS resolves the dependencies for you.

I suggest that you use npm and [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to manage your modules. There're also lots of documents for them.

Let's say you want to create a single page application. When you use npm to install a lib, it downloads from the npm registry into node_modules in your local disk. How do you indicate the path of `node_modules/` folder in your html? The answer is you can't. Webpack does the task for you.

Webpack bundle all your javascript files and necessary dependencies (files in your local node_modules) into a big file. Then you can set the path to the `<script src="...">` in your html.